# how to increase the div height dynamically based on the image present inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

```
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">

      <span class="closed" onclick="closeModal()">
        <img
          data-src="img/close-left-product-ui-ux-design-cover.webp"
          style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"
          alt="close button"
          class="img-fluid lazyload"
        />
      </span>

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="my-slides">

          <img
            src="img/image1@2x.webp"
            class="img-fluid lazyload"
            alt="ecolight product"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.my-slides {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-slides img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I want my class modal-content and class my-slides dynamically increase based on the height present inside it. With this code, the container height is not increasing. I have images with different heights. Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ronakradadiya/gh5joxrv/14/   I want white container to take space of that of the image. @palaѕн

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by using value [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#Values) for `height` CSS style for the `.modal-content` element like:

```
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: max-content;   
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c32h6qu8/)

Comment: Sorry I am so late for this. When I had set this height it is working perfect, but when I scroll down modal in chrome android(mobile devices only), white space appears at the bottom.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to test it as I mostly work on web applications. Please post a new question with your issue, all infos and also a demo so that other mobile devs can look into it and provide more insight into it. Thanks!

Comment: I meant about the webpage when viewed in mobile devices in chrome, this issue appears. I have already posted the issue. If you could help me, please. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780016/in-mobile-devices-using-chrome-in-android-when-i-scroll-down-the-modal-and-the/61798408?noredirect=1#comment109311416_61798408