# In mobile devices using chrome in android, when I scroll down the modal and the address bar disappears, white space appears at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("my-modal").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("nav").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "hidden";
}
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("my-modal").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("nav").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  margin-top: 55px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: max-content;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.my-slides {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-slides img {
  width: 100%;
}

.closed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.closed:hover,
.closed:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 8%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 8%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* Media queries */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .prev {
    left: 7%;
  }
  .next {
    right: 7%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .prev {
    display: none;
  }
  .next {
    display: none;
  }
  .modal-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px) {
  .prev {
    display: none;
  }
  .next {
    display: none;
  }
  .modal-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">
  <!-- close button -->
  <span class="closed" onclick="closeModal()">
        <img
          data-src="img/close-left-product-ui-ux-design-cover.webp"
          style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"
          alt="close button"
          class="img-fluid lazyload"
        />
      </span>
  <!-- content for modal -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Images for modal -->
    <div class="my-slides">
      <!-- <div class="numbertext">1/15</div> -->
      <img data-src="img/ecolight-product-ui-ux-design-full@3x.webp" class="img-fluid lazyload" alt="ecolight product" />
    </div>
    <div class="my-slides">
      <!-- <div class="numbertext">1/15</div> -->
      <img data-src="img/demo-product-ui-ux-design-cover-full@3x.webp" class="img-fluid lazyload" alt="demo product" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="changeSlides(-1)">
    <img data-src="img/left-product-ui-ux-design-cover.webp" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" class="img-fluid lazyload" alt="previous button" />
  </a>
  <a class="next" onclick="changeSlides(1)">
    <img data-src="img/right-product-ui-ux-design-cover.webp" class="img-fluid lazyload" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" alt="next button" />
  </a>
</div>
```

In mobile devices using chrome in android, when I scroll down the modal and the address bar disappears, white space appears at the bottom. This does not happen with any other browsers such as mozilla firefox, mi browser in android. It's just when address bar disappears, white space appears.

Here is the screenshot of an issue that I am facing.

[image]

The one with the red border is the white space that occurs when I scroll in chrome android.

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, but I can't see any modal.. Can you edit the snippet and add a button or something that triggers the modal? So that it shows your problem?

Comment: https://portfolios-ronak.netlify.app/ux-ui-design-projects.html can you visit this working site. If you scroll down you will get plain blue colour image and on click an modal will appear. You can see there

Answer (score 0):

I think in't an little issue of a 100vh on some mobile browsers. 100vh - is 100% of a current viewport (all you can see on your screen). Sometimes it's a little bit unstable on mobile browsers while you scrolling up and down and the height of a browser changing dynamically due to navbar/addressbar hiding/appearing.

Try to change following setting

```
body {
  min-height: 100%; /* on your example link it is 100hv, make it 100% */
}
.modal {
  min-height: 100%; /* the element is fixed, it will work hike whith 100%; */
}
```

If this wouldn't help - please, make a screenshot of an issue.

Comment: I tried this still not working. Screenshot of an issue like ?

Comment: If I put overflow-x:hidden to html, it works fine. But 2 scrollbars appears on modal, one for the modal itself and other for body.

Comment: Screenshot of an issue, yes

Comment: Meaning What I have to do ?

Comment: Take a screenshot with white space on android chrome

Comment: and post it here

Comment: Yeah. And post in in your answer or sent a ling in comment here

Comment: I am sorry for asking so many questions. But why I have to put screenshot in my answer because it is not resolved.

Comment: Hm. Maybe there is some misunderstanding. Take a screenshot of an issue, edit your question (not answer, i'm sorry. )

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213865/discussion-between-focus-style-and-ronak-patel).

Comment: Hi guys, I faced the same issue, still no reproduced on firefox mobile or safari, did you find a fix ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my case by using height: -webkit-fill-available instead of height: 100vh on mobile devices. But you have to find which div you have to set. It's quite tricky when you have more inner divs.